# perl printing table output

Tags: perl, string-formatting

I am trying to print output in tabular format.

my Script:

```
use strict;
my @heading=("FN","SN","BP","SUBBN","LgcBT");
my @values=("1","0","Front","Mother Board","MIU");
print "\n\n";
&HEADING;
print "\n";
&VALUES;
print "\n\n";

sub HEADING {
    foreach (@heading) {
        my $lgth1=length($_);
        printf "%3s","| ";
        printf "%${lgth1}s",$_;
    }
}

sub VALUES {
    foreach (@values) {
        my $lgth2=length($_);
        printf "%3s","| ";
        printf "%${lgth2}s",$_;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 | FN | SN | BP | **SUBBN** | LgcBT

 | 1 | 0 | Front | **Mother Board** | MIU
```

**I need to print output in a way that if value is longer than heading then it automatically adjusts length of heading to that of value.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to generate a length array in advance:

```
my @lengths;
for (0..$#lengths) {
    $lengths[$_] = (length($headers[$_]) > length($values[$_])) ? length($headers[$_]) : length($values[$_])
}
```

Of course, there are better ways to generate `@lengths` that are more Perl-ish, but IMHO this example is the easiest to read.

Comment: Hello Nathan, Thanks for the code.   Since I am networking guy can you elaborate me more how can I use the provided code in my existing script which is in initial post....sorry for the trouble...

Comment: @Mahesh: after you generate the `@lengths` array, just use that instead of the `3` in `%3s` and instead of `${lgth2}` and `${lgth1}`.

Comment: Oh my god nathan...this is really amazing...thanks a lot.....It works...Regards: Mahesh

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you should just use [Data::Format::Pretty::Console](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aPretty%3a%3aConsole)

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of modules for 'pretty-printing' text tables; my favourite is [Text::ASCIITable](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aASCIITable).

Comment: N.B. Quentin's suggestion uses yours as a backend

Comment: That's good to know - sounds like Data::Format is a more flexible solution.